# Adding a column header to a csv in python

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a csv that contains just 1 column of domain names that range from about 300 to 1500 lines, looking similar to the following:

```
google.com
abc.net
yahoo.com
cnn.com
twitter.com
```

All I need to do is add a column header of "domain" so my csv will look like:

```
domain
google.com
abc.net
yahoo.com
cnn.com
twitter.com
```

I attempted the following using pandas:

```
from pandas import read_csv
x = read_csv('domains.csv')
x.columns = ['domain']
x.to_csv('out.csv')
```

This results in a csv with the added column header, but it also added an additional column with the row numbers, which I don't want... what am I doing wrong?

```
    domain
0   google.com
1   abc.net
2   yahoo.com
3   cnn.com
4   twitter.com
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to set `index=False` when writing `to_csv` to remove the additional column:

```
x.to_csv('out.csv',index=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you are doing is adding one line, you don't really need pandas to do this. Here is an example using the normal python file writing modules:

```
with open('domains.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    rows = [r for r in csvfile]
    rows = ['domain'] + rows

with open('domains.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    for row in rows:
        csvfile.write(row + '\n')
```

Comment: I think this is the best solution, +1

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`header`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) parameter in `to_csv` as you have just 1 column in your dataframe.

```
df = pd.read_csv(data, header=None)
df.to_csv('out.csv', header=['domain'], index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add parameter `names` to [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) and `index=False` to [`to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Datarame.to_csv.html):

```
x = read_csv('domains.csv', names=['domain'])
```

Sample:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u"""google.com
abc.net
yahoo.com
cnn.com
twitter.com"""
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
x = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), names=['domain'])
print (x)
        domain
0   google.com
1      abc.net
2    yahoo.com
3      cnn.com
4  twitter.com

#need remove index
x.to_csv('filename',index=False)
```